# Transfer Objects from another App into a ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I've made a Choice Field for HTML File with this simple code:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('0', 'Johnny B. Goode'),
    ('1', 'Lightning McQueen'),
    ('2', 'Iron Man'),
)

def get_student():
    student_data = MY_CHOICES
    student_list = student_data
    return student_list

def get_my_students():
    student_list = get_student()
    choices_list = student_list
    return choices_list

class studentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(studentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_students_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_my_students())


def get_data(request):
    form = studentForm()
    if form:
        print('form')
        return render_to_response('bills/generator.html',{'form': form})
    else:
        return print('no Form')
```

My problem now is, that MY_CHOICES is a normal Tuple with some arguments that are shown up in my view, but I want to take Objects, who are stored in another app called "Students" (want to export "first_name" + "last_name") instead of the entries in MY_CHOICES.
The objects are stored in this class:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_(u'Vorname'),max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_(u'Nachname'),max_length=30)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postal_code = models.CharField(_(u'Postleitzahl'),max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(_(u'Ort'),max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

So I'm searching for a kind of strategic way, how to solve that problem. Hopefully someone can give me a hint.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Btw I understand you're a musician, but in Python you have `tuples`, not **tuplets**

Comment: Your existing code doesn't make much sense. `get_my_students` does nothing other than return the result of `get_student`, which in turn does nothing but return the value of MY_CHOICES. Why do you have either of those functions?

Comment: I thought it would be better to get the objects from the other app with get_students(). In this stage it really doesnt make a sense

Comment: I want to take first_name + last_name from the class Student in the app "Students" and put it into the tuple MY_CHOICES. So that it would be something like: MY_CHOICES = (
    ('0', 'Student A'),
    ('1', 'Student B'),
    ('2', 'Student C'),
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this quite a bit harder than it needs to be. You don't want to take the names from Student and "put it into the tuple MY_CHOICES". The tuple is irrelevant. What you want is to have a field that is populated from the Student model, and there is a form field especially for that: [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield). You can just use it directly:

```
from students.models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.Form):
    student = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.all())
```

You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: I tried you solution. Unfortunately, nothing shows up in the HTML-File. So I did a print(form) and django showed me this code: <tr><th><label for="id_student">Student:</label></th><td><select name="student" required id="id_student">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">Mario Butcher</option>

</select></td></tr> so the code work, but do you know why it doesn't show up in at my page?

Comment: Please post your view and template.

Comment: Found the mistake! Spelling issue on {{ form.student(s) }} Thank you very much Mr Roseman!